# REDSHIFT ERROR ON USING LISTAGG: One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm using listagg() in redshift and the where condition has is null check for a bigint column which is a primary key.

The query:

**select listagg(display_id) from ticket where account_id is null;**

and it throws the error:

**One or more of the used functions must be applied on at least one user created tables. Examples of user table only functions are LISTAGG, MEDIAN, PERCENTILE_CONT, etc**

the column detail is:

*Column | Type| Collation | Nullable*

**account_id | bigint| | not null**

The goal is to fetch no data for a particular account_id
Is there any alternate to **listagg()** or a way to solve this issue?

Comment: please share your sql and some example data if possible (edit your question)

Comment: can you try select listagg(display_id::text) from ticket where account_id is null;

Comment: the sql is: select listagg(display_id) from ticket where account_id is null; and  select listagg(display_id::text) from ticket where account_id is null; is not working either

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in Redshift `listagg` does not work on queries with a "where" clause that is *always* false. In question account_id is never null because the table definition disallows it.

Unfortunately the Redshift error text does nothing to make this apparent, but there is a related thread on the AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=242096

You can test this by running the following examples on Redshift

```
-- Create a temp table with not null account_id

create table #ticket (display_id int, account_id bigint not null);
insert into #ticket values (1,1), (1,2), (2,4), (3, 5), (3,1);

-- This query like the example in the question fails because the where clause always evaluates to false
select listagg(display_id) from #ticket where account_id is null;

-- This fails with the same error
select listagg(display_id) from #ticket where false;

-- But both these example succeed
select listagg(display_id) from #ticket;
select listagg(display_id) from #ticket where true;
```

Here is the same example but this time the table does allow null values for account_id, and the query succeeds.

```
-- Create another temp table that allows null account_id

create table #ticket2 (display_id int, account_id bigint);
insert into #ticket2 values (1,1), (1,2), (2,null), (3, null), (3,1);

-- This query like the example in the question now suceeds
select listagg(display_id) from #ticket2 where account_id is null;

-- These also succeed
select listagg(display_id) from #ticket2;
select listagg(display_id) from #ticket2 where true;

-- This one fails with the same error
select listagg(display_id) from #ticket2 where false;
```